# Firebase Real time Database giving notification on my android app every time when any of child node value is changes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cloud

Hey I am implementing Notification functionality in my app, which is If any of the driver image changes if should give me a notification alert on my mobile app. The function I've implemented is working perfectly fine.
But if any of the child node value change in that specific driver(user), it gives me a notification too.
I want to Recieve a notification on **just** change of Image.

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                drowsinessDriversList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2:snapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    driverModel = dataSnapshot2.getValue(DriverModel.class);
                    // Assigned variable is important
                    adminUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    if(adminUID.equals(driverModel.getAssignTo())) {

                        if (driverModel.getStatus().equals("Assigned")) {
                            drowsinessDriversList.add(driverModel);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(driverDrowsinessAdapter);
                            Log.d("jawad", "arraylist.inner" + driverModel.getEmail());
                        }
                    }


        stringNotification = driverModel.getDrowsinessImage();
        if (stringNotification.equals("--")){
          //  Toast.makeText(AdminHomeActivity.this, "if condition: "+stringNotification, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(AdminHomeActivity.this, "else condition: "+stringNotification, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notifyAdminDriverIsDrowsy();
        }

                }
                driverDrowsinessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: @AlexMamo When I run this code on Physical device it gives me notification in datachange of other (node values) as well, in this case I am also getting user location in foreground service after every 4000 milliseconds. So it also give notification on change of location after every 4000 miliseconds that I dont want to recieve! I just wanted to recieve notification if the drowsyImage changes I am receiving value of drowsyImage node through Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener only to that particular field? And take action, only when it is changed?

Comment: Please see the code I'm already getting the reference of drowsyImage in string

Comment: stringNotification = driverModel.getDrowsinessImage();

Comment: The block of code I provided is surrounded with addValueEventListener